# Clarification needed regarding DeMorgan's Law

Tags: logic, intuition, propositional-calculus

I'm currently going through Daniel Velleman's "How to Prove It". He states DeMorgan's Law as follows:

> **1.** $\neg (P\wedge Q)$ is equivalent to $\neg P \vee \neg Q$ 
>   **2.** $\neg (P \vee Q)$ is equivalent to $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$

The best way I knew to convince myself of the truth of these laws is by creating basic analogies. I used the following statements:

> $P=$ I will eat strawberry ice cream 
>   $Q=$ I will eat chocolate ice cream

---

### 1. $\neg (P \wedge Q)$ is equivalent to $\neg P \vee \neg Q$

$\neg (P \wedge Q)$: is equivalent to saying **I will not eat both strawberry and chocolate ice cream**. 
$\neg P \vee \neg Q$: is equivalent to saying **I will not eat strawberry ice or I will not eat chocolate ice cream**

### 2. $\neg (P \vee Q)$ is equivalent to $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$

$\neg (P \vee Q)$: is equivalent to saying: **I will not eat either strawberry ice cream or chocolate ice cream**

$\neg P \wedge \neg Q$: is equivalant to saying **I will not eat strawberry ice cream and I will not eat chocolate ice cream**

---

Having drawn these analogies I'm at a loss to see how the two laws differ.
Is it possible using the same analogies someone can clarify the finer distinctions between the two laws. Thank you.

Comment: The first one $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q$ is true if I will eat an ice cream with strawberry but **no** vanilla, while the second $\lnot P \land \lnot Q$ is not true in this case.

Comment: Please point out where the difference is?

Comment: @EmmadKareem that's what I'm trying to work out.. I don't know the differences between the various statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. "I will not eat both strawberry and chocolate ice cream" in the intended sense,
   i.e. "It is not the case that I will eat both strawberry and chocolate ice cream"

is obviously distinct from

4. "I will not eat strawberry ice cream and I will not eat chocolate ice cream".

Suppose I eat strawberry but not chocolate. 3 then is true and 4 false.

3 and 4  show that (1a) $\neg(P \land Q)$ is distinct from (2a) $\neg P \land \neg Q$

---

5. "I will not eat strawberry ice or I will not eat chocolate ice cream"

is also obviously distinct from

6. "I will not eat either strawberry ice cream or chocolate ice cream".

Suppose I don't eat strawberry but do eat chocolate. Then 3 is true and 4 false.

5 and 6 show that (1b) $\neg P \lor \neg Q$ is distinct from (2b) $\neg (P \lor Q)$.

---

Hence the  claim (1), that 1a is equivalent to 1b, is indeed a distinct claim from the claim (2), that 2a is equivalent to 2b.

Answer (score 0):

The statements are equivalent.  Start with

$$\lnot (P \land Q) = \lnot P \lor \lnot Q$$

Substitute $\lnot A = P$ and $\lnot B = Q$

$$\lnot (\lnot A \land \lnot B) = \lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B = A \lor B$$

Negate both sides:

$$\lnot A \land \lnot B = \lnot (A \lor B)$$

Which is the second Demorgan's law.